# Winforms showing different values from xml

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, windows-services

I have a windows service project which contains a Test.xml file. In the properies it is changed to copy always.

I have created a setup for service and after installing the service the Test.xml is present in the C:\program files(86)\service folder.

Now I want to edit the Test.xml file throgh a UI. So i have created a small Winforms project 'EditXml'. The EditXml is accessing the Test.xml like this

```
document = XDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test.xml"));
```

I have added the EditXml.exe  also to the setup of services. So after installing the service the EditXml.exe is also present in the folder.

But when I edit using  EditXml I cant see the changes in test.xml.

Why values are different from Test.xml? Is this a correct approach? Let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: It is not clear. What difference? how you compare files? how you show values of xml in your small application?

Comment: I want to edit the xml file which is present in C:\program files(86)\service folder after service installation. Suppose the xml contains a value 50 then my EditXml application shows different value.

Comment: Are you using the save method of xdocument to write back to the file?

Comment: yes. i am using xdocument to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have an issue with inssuficient permissions and windows file virtualization. When your installer creates a file inside Program Files folder, it usually sets permission only for read operations.

When you try to modify the file using an application running at user account that has now write permissions, windows makes an illusion that the file has been successfully written, but puts it in a virtual store - check if such directory/file exists in c:\users\CurrentUserName\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\YourFolderName

Only your application can see modified file version, but all other application see original version written by installer.

To be able to modify the file using an application, you need to add write permissions to the file.

Comment: how to set write permission to a file inside Program Files folder?

Comment: You can set it manually after installation using a windows dialog - just to test if this is really an issue. If you ask how to configure file in setup service with write permissions, so it installs with write permission set, it depends on which setup toolset you use. (I know how to configure this using WiX toolset, but it might not be your case.)

Comment: I have checked the xml. It has write permission.

Comment: I would also try if you can edit your file with another application and successfully read your changes. If it works, it might be another issue, then.

Comment: I can edit the xml using another application. But the changes are not reflecting.

Comment: I would search if your xml file got created in the virtual store c:\users\(YourUserName)\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\(YourApplicationSubFolder). If found, delete whole application directory from the virtual store. If it gets created again, it means that you still have insufficient permissions to write to the file. I would also check that you have both write and modify permission to your file.